# VBA - Logging into Website - Login Button

Tags: vba, web-scraping

Good afternoon all,

Please forgive me, I am new to VBA and have been practicing within my workbooks but for my work would be highly useful to branch out to Webscraping.

The following is my code.

```
Sub pullsalesdatafromonline()

Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "https://www.peoplestuffuk.com/WFMMCDPRD/Login.jsp"

Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set doc = IE.document

doc.getElementById("txtUserID").Click

doc.getElementById("txtUserID").Value = Usernameinserted

doc.getElementById("txtPassword").Click

doc.getElementById("txtPassword").Value = PasswordInserted

doc.getElementById("Login").Click

IE.navigate "https://www.peoplestuffuk.com/WFMMCDPRD/LoginSubmit.jsp"

IE.navigate "https://www.peoplestuffuk.com/WFMMCDPRD/ModuleSelection.jsp"

IE.navigate "https://www.peoplestuffuk.com/WFMMCDPRD/dashboard/main/dashboardmain.jsp"

IE.navigate "https://www.peoplestuffuk.com/WFMMCDPRD/rrd/matrixReport.jsp?fromPM=N"

End Sub
```

Here is the element that I am trying to scrape from;

```
<INPUT onclick=javaScript:submitForm() class=button-t type=button value=Login>
<SPAN id=Login_span class=buttonbox></SPAN>
```

I've looked at several other links that have looked into firing the .onclick event but, can't quite seem to figure it out.

The error in VBA highlights the:

```
IE.navigate "https://www.peoplestuffuk.com/WFMMCDPRD/ModuleSelection.jsp"
```

line. When my username and password enter, the page refreshes/ tries to exectute and then empties the Login and password info and leaves me on the Login page.

Would greatly appreciate someone's input.

Thank you

Comment: Did you run the script to see whether it worked @Rob161?

Comment: Hi SIM, sorry for not getting back to you. Unfortunatly it did not. Same issue as before. The page will seem to refresh after there seems to be an attempt to login in, however will then proceed to say incorrect user/pass word and not continue. I can assure the username and password I use are correct. Unfortunately I would not be able to share a user id/ pass and we do not hold a simulator user/key to help you with your request.  Any other ideas, would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a demo username and password to share then there was an efficient way of logging in using xhr. However, as for your current attempt concern, they are not the ids you used them within `.getElementById()`. Given that the following approach should log you in. Make sure to uncomment the delay, if the script fails to do the doing.

```
Sub pullsalesdatafromonline()
    Dim IE As Object, doc As HTMLDocument

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    IE.navigate "https://www.peoplestuffuk.com/WFMMCDPRD/Login.jsp"

    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")

    Set doc = IE.document

    doc.querySelector("[name='txtUserID']").innerText = "username"
    doc.querySelector("[name='txtPassword']").innerText = "password"

'    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
    doc.querySelector("input[value='Login']").Click
End Sub
```